# Listing images horizontally on a webpage using html?

Tags: html, css

```html
<div id="FirsRowImg">
  <div class="ImgCell">
    <a class="linkopacity" href="services_backdrops.html" >
      <img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/League%20of%20Legends-272x380.jpg" border="0" >
      <p>Backdrops &amp; Drapes</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="ImgCell">
    <a class="linkopacity" href="services_balloons.html" >
      <img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/For%20Honor-272x380.jpg" border="0" >
      <p>Balloons</p>
    </a>
  </div>
...etc etc...
</div>
```

I want to display images horizontally similar to how this website does theirs: https://www.twitch.tv/directory

but my list does not come out anything like that. It lists the images vertically. If it helps, the webpage i am using is being hosted on zetaboard.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably using flexbox with `flex-wrap`

```css
#FirsRowImg {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.ImgCell {
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
}
```

```html
    <div id="FirsRowImg">
      <div class="ImgCell">
        <a class="linkopacity" href="services_backdrops.html" >
          <img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/League%20of%20Legends-272x380.jpg" border="0" >
          <p>Backdrops &amp; Drapes</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="ImgCell">
        <a class="linkopacity" href="services_balloons.html" >
          <img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/For%20Honor-272x380.jpg" border="0" >
          <p>Balloons</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Or you can use `inline-block`

```css
.ImgCell {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="FirsRowImg">
      <div class="ImgCell">
        <a class="linkopacity" href="services_backdrops.html" >
          <img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/League%20of%20Legends-272x380.jpg" border="0" >
          <p>Backdrops &amp; Drapes</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="ImgCell">
        <a class="linkopacity" href="services_balloons.html" >
          <img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/For%20Honor-272x380.jpg" border="0" >
          <p>Balloons</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Or `float` the elements

```css
#FirsRowImg {
  overflow: auto;
}
.ImgCell {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="FirsRowImg">
      <div class="ImgCell">
        <a class="linkopacity" href="services_backdrops.html" >
          <img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/League%20of%20Legends-272x380.jpg" border="0" >
          <p>Backdrops &amp; Drapes</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="ImgCell">
        <a class="linkopacity" href="services_balloons.html" >
          <img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/For%20Honor-272x380.jpg" border="0" >
          <p>Balloons</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in three different rules.

Rule 1:

```
.ImgCell{display: inline-block;width: 49%;}
```

Rule 2:

```
.ImgCell{float:left;width: 50%;}
```

Rule 3:

```
#FirsRowImg {display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap;}
```

Note: Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions do not support the flex property.

Note: Internet Explorer 10 supports an alternative, the -ms-flex property. IE11 and newer versions fully support the flex property (do not need the -ms- prefix).

Note: Safari 6.1 (and newer) supports an alternative, the -webkit-flex property.